# Map reduce job gets stuck in accepted state

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am having local installation og hadoop on my mac book air 8gb , but my mapreduce job gets stuck in Accepted state, wanted to know if i am missing something in the configurations, what am i doing wrong here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Scheduler and check the "default" queue for this account name. 
Probably one of those pairs have the almost similar value:

- "Max resources" and "Used resources" - the account used all allowed
  to him resources and can't allocate new containers to run a new job.
- "Max AM Resource" and "Used AM Resource" - there is no more allowed
  resources to allocate an Application Manager container and start the job.